# Do I have to deactive an INDEX before INSERTING?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table with a clustered index on a column it.

I have a procedure that truncates this table and inserts new and updated data into it.

**What would be the best process Procedure for it?**

1. DROP the index first?
2. TRUNCATE the table
3. INSERT the table
4. CREATE the index again?

Its a table for a SSRS-Report. A SSRS-Report access this table and showing the data. My goal is to reduce the accesstime. So the user see the SSRS-Report faster.

Comment: If this table has a primary key on it then it's likely other tables will have foreign keys referencing it - so you won't be able to delete the contents of the table, nor truncate it, due to constraint violations. Why do you feel the need to truncate the table and re-insert the data? Can you not just insert new data and update the existing data?

Comment: Do you *have to*... no - what is your goal - is this some sort of stageing table? Is your insert's performance mission critical? Are you inserting millions of rows? A heap may be best in this case - the answer is the usual *it depends* - on information you haven't provided.

Comment: Its a table for a SSRS-Report. A SSRS-Report access this table and showing the data. My goal is to reduce the accesstime. So the user see the SSRS-Report faster.

Comment: I created a clustered index on the customer_id, and remove the primary key. So this key can not used as foreign key.

Comment: The process above works, but is this a best process available.

Comment: As has been mentioned, we don't have enough information. The fact the data is used by an SSRS report is likely irrelevant here.

Comment: It seems odd one would truncate and reload a permanent table for a report. Consider the implications if different users execute the proc at the same time. It seems a temporary table might be more appropriate or there might be other techniques, but we can's suggest without seeing the code.

Comment: The step of adding a clustered index to a heap just copies the entirety of the data to a new set of pages structured as a clustered index so this renders the initial insert to a heap fairly pointless compared to just inserting into an empty clustered index in the first place

Comment: Might be worth utilizing table switching? As documented here https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching

Comment: _is this a best process available._ No one but you knows how you measure best nor exactly what "access time" means. And it is unusual to have "a table for a SSRS-Report". Why exactly do you need a "report table"? And following this logic, do you intend to create a table for each report provided by your system? If two people run your report at the same time, what do you expect to happen? I think your current design is flawed in a multi-user system but perhaps that isn't a concern here.

Comment: I recreate this table once per day. So I run this procedure once a day, to update my data. They a SSRS-Report access this table. If I use an Index on the table, i think the Report can select the relevant of this table faster.

Comment: why don't
 you create a new non-clustered index which matches your where clause/join columns. in that way update stats can easily recalc then the next time you use it it will be a lot faster.